# net maui editor control is converting line breaks to spaces

Tags: c#, maui

I have a Maui app with an editor
with `isReadOnly="true"`. When my app writes text with line breaks, the editor converts the line breaks to spaces.

How do I fix that?

Comment: I think it is because c# uses carriage return, not line break, to separate lines. Process your incoming text, change all line break characters to carriage returns. Or in a literal test string, `"first line\nsecond line"`. Does that work any better?